# Does anyone have experience working to export documents in reqif format from Polarion?

Tags: automation, export, polarion, reqif

I want to automate the process of exporting documents from Polarion in `reqif` format but I could not find any APIs or WSDL that allow such a feature. I wonder if anyone has a similar use case and has a good solution for it. I'd be glad to hear some creative input, thanks.